# trouble with constructs after adding view to contentView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to add a target to an image in a tableview, but it doesn't work if I don't add a view to the contentView. After that, my constraints broke.
https://github.com/termyter/stackoverflow-search

before[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPC25.jpg)

after[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nPBl.png)

PostController

```
import Foundation
 import UIKit

protocol AnswerhNetworkDelegate: AnyObject {
    func getListModels(noteModels: [AnswerModel])
}

class PostController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, AnswerhNetworkDelegate{
    func getListModels(noteModels: [AnswerModel]) {
        listModels += noteModels
        table.reloadData()
    }
    
    private var listModels: [AnswerModel] = []
    private var searchText = UITextField()
    private var searchButton = UIButton()
    private var table = UITableView()
    private let answerNetwork = AnswerNetwork()
    var model: PostModel = PostModel.empty 



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground

        table.register(PostCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostCell")
        table.register(CustomAnswerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomAnswerCell")
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self

        table.estimatedRowHeight = 68.0
        table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension


        setupUI()
        answerNetwork.answerNetworkDelegate = self

        //переделать
        answerNetwork.fetch(idPost: model.id)
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            table.reloadData()

        }


    private func setupUI() {
        table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        table.separatorStyle = .none
        view.addSubview(table)

        table.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        table.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        table.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        listModels.count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as? PostCell else {
                fatalError("не CustomCell")
            }
//            cell.cellView.image.userInteractionEnabled =
            let lpgr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostController.handleTapPress(_:)))
            cell.cellView.image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.cellView.image.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
            
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.model = model
            
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomAnswerCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomAnswerCell else {
                fatalError("не CustomCell")
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.model = listModels[indexPath.row - 1]
            return cell
        }
    }

    @objc func handleTapPress(_ sender: Any){
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: model.link)!)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
    
}

extension String {

    init?(htmlEncodedString: String) {

        guard let data = htmlEncodedString.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(attributedString.string)

    }

}
```

PostCell

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PostCell: UITableViewCell {

    var cellView = PostView()
    private var selectedButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var model: PostModel? {
        get {
            cellView.model
        }
        set {
            cellView.model = newValue ?? PostModel.empty
        }
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .white
        setupView()
//        print(cellView.frame)
//        print(contentView.frame)
//        print(self.frame)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        isHidden = false
        isSelected = false
        isHighlighted = false

        self.model = PostModel.empty
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupView() {
        cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(cellView)
//        addSubview(cellView)
        cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
    }
}
```

PostView is in the PostCell as a cell and is injected with the Model

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

class PostView: UIView {
    private var titleText = UILabel()
    private var bodyText = UILabel()
    private var nameText = UILabel()
    var image = UIImageView()
    private var dateText = UILabel()
    private var answerCount = UILabel()
    var model: PostModel = PostModel.empty {
        didSet {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YYY"
            titleText.text = model.title
            image.load(urlString: model.image)
            nameText.text = "Автор:" + model.name
            dateText.text = "Дата: " + formatter.string(from: model.date)
            answerCount.text = "Кол-во ответов: " + String(model.answer_count)
            bodyText.text = model.body
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        setupTitleText()
        setupImage()
        let tapGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped))
        image.addGestureRecognizer(tapGR)
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        setupNameText()
        setupDateText()
        setupAnswerCount()
        setupBodyText()
    }

    @objc func imageTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            if sender.state == .ended {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: model.link)!)
            }
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupTitleText() {
        titleText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        titleText.numberOfLines = 0
        let maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 9999)
        let expectedLabelSize: CGSize = titleText.sizeThatFits(maximumLabelSize)
        var newFrame: CGRect = titleText.frame
        newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height
        titleText.frame = newFrame

        addSubview(titleText)
        titleText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        titleText.leadingAnchor.constraint( equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        titleText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    private func setupImage() {
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        addSubview(image)
        image.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleText.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        image.leadingAnchor.constraint( equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        image.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true
        //image.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    private func setupNameText() {
        nameText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(nameText)
        nameText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleText.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        nameText.leadingAnchor.constraint( equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        nameText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    private func setupDateText() {
        dateText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(dateText)
        dateText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameText.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        dateText.leadingAnchor.constraint( equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        dateText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    }

    private func setupAnswerCount() {
        answerCount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(answerCount)
        answerCount.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateText.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        answerCount.leadingAnchor.constraint( equalTo: image.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        answerCount.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
//        answerCount.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

    private func setupBodyText() {
        bodyText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        bodyText.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)


        bodyText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        bodyText.numberOfLines = 0
        let maximumLabelSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 280, height: 9999)
        let expectedLabelSize: CGSize = bodyText.sizeThatFits(maximumLabelSize)
        // create a frame that is filled with the UILabel frame data
        var newFrame: CGRect = bodyText.frame
        // resizing the frame to calculated size
        newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height
        // put calculated frame into UILabel frame
        bodyText.frame = newFrame

        addSubview(bodyText)
        bodyText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: answerCount.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        bodyText.leadingAnchor.constraint( equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        bodyText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        bodyText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

on this github, I looked at how he arranges the constraints and made it for himself https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section/blob/master/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section/CollapsibleTableViewCell.swift

and redid PostCell

```
    private func setupView() {

        let marginGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(cellView)
        cellView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        cellView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        cellView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: marginGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```